# REST design for API accessing multiple resources

Tags: rest

Imagine an API that returns JSON data for a TV listings app like [zap2it TV listings.](http://tvlistings.zap2it.com/tvlistings/ZCGrid.do?aid=zap2it)

It's basically a list of TV channels and for each channel the shows that are on currently and beyond. Currently, I have an API that returns all the channels `GET /channels`. However, there is a need to add the show currently on for each channel in that data. I am thinking of adding a new API, `GET /channels/on_now`, to differentiate it from the current API. **I want to be clear about this for the new API, I don't want to make individual call for each channel, the show-on-now data needs to be returned for all channels.** Is this a good REST API design?

Current `GET /channels` JSON data

```
[
   "channel": {
      "channelName": "KRON4",
    },
   "channel": {
      "channelName": "KTOV5",
    },
   ...
]
```

Expected JSON data for new API `GET /channels/on_now` below

```
[
  {
   "channel": {
      "channelName": "KRON4",
    },
    "on_now": {
      "startTime": "2012-06-04T11:30:00",
      "endTime": "2012-06-04T12:00:00",
      "shortDescription": "Latest local, statewide & national news events, along with sports & weather.",
      "shortTitle": "4:30am Newscast"
    }
  },
  {
   "channel": {
      "channelName": "KTOV5",
    },
    "on_now": {
      "startTime": "2012-06-04T11:30:00",
      "endTime": "2012-06-04T12:30:00",
      "shortDescription": "Local morning news and weather report",
      "shortTitle": "Morning Newscast"
    }
  },
  ...next channel...
]
```

Comment: Hi Bob, i was lloking for zap2it TV listings RESTful API, but could not get anything on internet please can you provide link for REST API of zap2it TV listings.

Answer (score 3):

I would advice to concentrate on *content*, not on URLs.

Example: you've got an entry point, '/'. This is the only URL in the API. GET on it return st like

```
{
    "channels" : {
        "href" : "path.to/channels"
        },
    "programs" : {
        "href" : "path.to/programs"
        }
}
```

To retrieve the list of channels, you GET on the corresponding URL - which you then don't need to know before - and obtain, for example:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "BBC",
        "id" : 452,
        "href" : "path.to/channels/452"
    },
    {
        "name" : "FOO",
        "id"   : 112,
        "href" : "path.to/channels/112"
    }
]
```

For detailled information about BBC, you GET on the provided URL:

```
{
    "name" : "BBC",
    "id" : 452,
    "self" : "path.to/channels/452",
    "live_url" : "link.to.bbc.cast",
    "whatever" : "bar",
    "current" : "path.to/channels/452/current",
    "program" : "path.to/channels/452/program"
}
```

And so on. URLs are discovered on the fly; you are free to modify them anytime. What makes your API is the content: you have to agree with clients about what is returned (fields, types, ...).
You finally call the "current" URL above to obtain information about current program.

Read here for more: http://kellabyte.com/2011/09/04/clarifying-rest/

**Edit after OP-comment:**

You could introduce an 'embed' parameter so as to limit amount of requests:

```
GET path.to/channels/452?embed=current
```

would return:

```
{
    "name" : "BBC",
    "id" : 452,
    "self" : "path.to/channels/452",
    "live_url" : "link.to.bbc.cast",
    "whatever" : "bar",
    "current" : {
        "self" : "path.to/channels/452/current",
        "name" : "Morning Show",
        "start_time" : "(datetime here)",
        "end_time"   : "(datetime here)",
        "next"       : "whatever.comes.ne/xt"
        },
    "program" : "path.to/channels/452/program"
}
```

Comment: Making the top level a discovery service is a good idea but it still doesn't address my fundamental need, please see updated question.

Comment: I solved this for my needs following way: I stick to the entity oriented transactions, and introduced an 'embed' parameter: GET path.to/channels/452?embed=current would return the data as above, including expanded data for the 'current' attribute. See my edit.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but even with the updated example, I still need to make a separate call for each channel, in your case, BBC with id 452. I don't want that, I want 1 call that returns all the channels and for each channel, what's on now.

Comment: I'd say that nothing prevents you from defining the content type for list of channels as you wish: the GET path.to/channels may return whatever you define, including a list of detailled information about each channel with current program, as you showed in your latest edit of the question. It may then make sense to introduce a new conceptual entity, i.e. return this information upon 'GET /on_air' for example.

Comment: Is `GET /on_air` any more RESTful than `GET channels/on_now`?

Comment: I personnaly prefer 'GET /on_now' (or /on_air, whichever) to 'GET /channels/on_now', because I'd like to keep '/channels' as an entity that i can index, query ('GET /channels/543'), update ('PUT /channels/134'), create ('POST /channels') or delete ('DELETE /channels/234'). Appending 'on_now' does not fit to this (my) view.

Comment: I can't quite tell which URLs you think can be indexed, is it `GET /channels` and `GET /channels/543`? And you are saying it's not possible to index `GET channels/on_now`? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: Index with 'GET /channels'. Sure, GET /channels/on_now is possible, you do whatever you want. Just : I don't like it, for the reasons above.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Is this a good REST API design?

**YES**, it is.

Contrary to the other people who have answered, you are free to define any resource you want to, as long as it represents a noun. That includes time-dependent services such as "what's on TV now" or the perrenial example, "current weather in <city>". These service resources are just as valid as more static ones representing a show or channel.

I would however change the URI. `/channels` looks like a collection resource URI. I would expect it's children to be channels, such as `/channels/kron4` (you can use any unique string, not jsut the ID, to identify instance resources).
As such, `/channels/on_now` looks odd. It looks like a channel called "on_now". Although there's nothing preventing you from using that, it may later conflict with a channel that *is* called "On Now"! **I would simply use `/on_now` as your URI.** `/channels/kron4/on_now` would obviously be good for a single channel's response too.

Answer (score 1):

```
/Channels -----------------------> Get All Channels
/Channels/bbc  ------------------> Get BBC Channel
/Channels/bbc/Shows -------------> Get All shows in BBC
/Channels/bbc/Shows/Baseball ----> Get the show called "Baseball", in bbc channel
/Channels/bbc/Shows/current -----> Get the Current show running, in bbc channel
```

Assuming you do not (and will not ) have a show called `Current` for any of your channels ! :) .

Comment: Good suggestion but that doesn't exactly work for my needs, see updated question for expected JSON data. I need the show-on-now info for each channel in the get-all-channels API.

Answer (score 1):

Just appending to the above answer:

```
/Channels/bbc/Shows/time/now -----> Get all the show played on BBC now
/Channels/bbc/Shows/time/2011-03-27T03:00:00.000+02:00 -----> Get all the show played on BBC  on 2011-03-27T03:00:00.000+02:00 .
```

This is more extensible and you wont have to worry about any show with the name current.

EDIT:
You can get a good headstart of doing such thing if you can get an api-doc access over here https://developer.sdp.nds.com/page/about

As per me, there would be more data needed and api would be something like:
//epg?time=&start=0&limit=1&duration=

This would define a generic api to get the location based tv_listing information based on time and duration. Result would be paginated with all the show between the channel listing occuring in the given time span.

Comment: I don't wish to make individual call for each channel, please see updated question.

Comment: I agree with Bart's answer for this, you should not be in channels path at all, use /shows?filter

Answer (score 1):

I'm no API expert, but I think you should be thinking in what you are returning instead of where 'looks like makes sense' to place the resource.

One solution will be to treat on_now as a resource.

so your api will be:

```
/channels (all channels)
/channels/{channel-id} (the {channel-id} channel - could be bbc and can have a collection of shows)
/channels/{channel-id}/shows (shows of channel-id)
/channels/{channel-id}/shows?filter=on_now (you are filtering a result, so i guess it's better to use query string, as if you were doing a query)
```

then you want to returns what's on now, that's no a property of the channel but a resource of itself. so how to implement that ?

```
/on_now/ (return a collection of on_now objects, which may be anything, channels, shows, whatever)
/on_now/?channel={channel-id} (this is a filter of the list by channel-id, you are just narrowing the list)
```

so isn't `/channels/{channel-id}/shows?filter=on_now`
the same as `/on_now/?channel={channel-id}` ?

actually, **NO**.

In the first uri you are getting shows filtered by a on_now.
In the second you are getting on_nows (which can be any representation, not exclusively a show) filtered by channel.

Why I think `on_now` should be treated as a resource and why is it important ?

While you make this resource separate, you can now have different representations of your resources. Also you have greater flexibility and no collision. Let's say tomorrow you want to show also in the on_now another 'show' that isn't on any channel, this can easily be done, on the other approachs it just has to be on a channel.
You can also later filter the on_now by different criteria, because they are independent objects.

You can also do:

```
/on_now/{on_now_id}
```

that will give details of the current show, like when it started, when it will end and also a place a location to `/shows/{show-id}` so you can reach it later after it's not on now anymore.

Yet, I think best solution would be to have shows as an unconnected resource to channel.
But the most important thing is, *i think* you should also need to ask yourself if you want shows to be underlying of channels...
And what hints to think of that is the

> `I don't want to make individual call for each channel, the
>   show-on-now data needs to be returned for all channels`

part.

That leads me to think that shows should NOT be inside the `/channels/` path.

That's because another approach will be to have `/shows/?filter=on_now` if you are only returning shows.

you can have:

```
/shows/?filters=on_now&channel=bbc
```

I like to think of resources as the 'thing' i'm returning instead of the standard thinking of relations alone. Underlying in the graph is great for properties, not so sure about collection of 'other things'.

Following the same example, I would rather have `/channels/{channel-id}/program` instead of `/channels/{channel-id}/shows`